# How do I alias a long package name without affecting the main package?

Tags: perl, perl-stash

If I have a really long package name, I can alias that package by making an entry in the symbol table:

```
BEGIN {
    # Make "Alias" be an alias for "Some::Really::Long::Package";
    *Alias:: = \*Some::Really::Long::Package::;
    # Equivalent to:
    # *main::Alias:: = \*Some::Really::Long::Package::;
}
```

This is what something like `Package::Alias` does for you internally.  However, this stinks because it mucks with the `main` package.  How can I make the alias only affect the current package, and be able to use just the alias within the package?  I tried changing the alias definition to

```
*Short::Alias:: = \*Some::Really::Long::Package::;
```

But then I have to use `Short::Alias->myMethod()` instead of just `Alias->myMethod()`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package Some::Really::Long::Package;

sub myMethod {
    print "myMethod\n";
}

package Short;

BEGIN {
    # Make "Alias" be an alias for "Some::Really::Long::Package";
    *Short::Alias:: = \*Some::Really::Long::Package::;
}

# I want this to work
Alias->myMethod();

package main;

# I want this to not work
Alias->myMethod();
```

---

**Bonus points** if both `Alias->myMethod()` and `Alias::myMethod()` work in the `Short` package, and not in `main`.

Comment: Alright, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you don't want to modify the symbol table of `main`, you could create a "package-local" alias with

```
package Short;

use constant Alias => 'Some::Really::Long::Package'; # create alias
Alias->myMethod(); # correctly calls myMethod() of package Some::Really::Long::Package
```

or alternatively

```
package Short;

sub Alias { Some::Really::Long::Package:: } # create alias
Alias->myMethod(); # correctly calls myMethod() of package Some::Really::Long::Package
```

Both examples should work as intended. Consequently, any attempt to call `Alias->myMethod()` from package `main` will obviously fail with

> Can't locate object method "myMethod" via package "Alias" (perhaps you forgot to load "Alias"?)

because the symbol table `%main::` or `%::` has no such entry called `Alias::`.

---

Due to the fact that you have several `package` calls in one file, you can also create `$alias` to reference `Some::Really::Long::Package`. Then you can limit the scope of `$alias` to the package `Short` to make it inaccessible from other places:

```
package Short;
{
   my $alias = Some::Really::Long::Package::; # create alias
   $alias->myMethod(); # correctly calls myMethod() of package Some::Really::Long::Package
}
```

---

EDIT (as response to the edited question):

The updated question is:

> Can both `Alias->myMethod()` and `Alias::myMethod()` work in the `Short` package but not in `main`?

I don't think so.

There are several options to make it work with the `->` syntax but not with the `::`. This is because perl seems to assume that a bareword like `Alias` followed by the package separator `::` represents the package `Alias` in the package `main`:

```
package Short;

Alias::myMethod();           # if you call myMethod(), you actually call it ...

::Alias::myMethod();         # ... like this, which is equivalent ...

main::Alias::myMethod();     # ... to this
```

All three calling options are equivalent, which demonstrates an important fact. If perl encounters something like `Foo::`, it starts looking in the package `main` first and not from the current (relative) location. So if I'm not missing something here, you can not use `Alias::myMethod()` without adding `Alias::` to `main`.

> This is what something like `Package::Alias` does for you internally. However, this stinks because it mucks with the `main` package.

Now, what I described above would also explain why modules like `Package::Alias` modify your `main` package, because there seem to be no way to avoid it.

Comment: Wouldn't `my $alias = Some::Really::Long::Package::;` work regardless of if the package definitions are all in one file? In practice I'd put them in different files, I just simplified the situation to pose the question succinctly.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you right. In your example where all `package` calls are in one file, the scalar `$alias` (declared with `my` inside `Short`) could be seen by all packages below (e.g. `main)`, because it's lexical scope is the entire file. As this is not what you want, I limited the scope of `$alias` with a `{}` block in the last example. If your packages are in their own files, `my` will make the variable completely private to it's package and thus inaccessible from all other/external packages.

Comment: I found why it doesn't work with `::` in the [perl source](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/01aeece0064776ef8376d241eb4e3e4692362c23:/gv.c#l1571).  When doing a lookup via `Alias::myMethod()`, `parse_gv_stash_name` is called with a null stash pointer, which causes perl to use the default stash, which is `main`.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't check the perl source. Thanks for pointing that out! I'm glad to see that my statement is consistent with the source.